# Localization in integral domains

Tags: maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization, integral-domain

Is it true that if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of an integral domain $A$, then $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is also an integral domain?

Comment: Every localisation of an integral domain is an integral domain.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown is this just because $(a/b)(r/s) = 0$ means $ar/bs = 0/1$, which means $ar = 0$, which means $a$ or $r$ is zero (as $A$ is a domain), thus either $(a/b)$ or $(r/s)$ is zero?